# Ruby Enumerable: first truthy value of a block

Tags: ruby, enumerable

In ruby we can do something like:

```
stuff_in_trash.detect(&:eatable?)
=> :pack_of_peanuts

stuff_in_trash.detect(&:drinkable?)
=> nil
```

But what if we are interested in the value of the block the first time it is truthy, rather than the first item for which the block takes a truthy value?

That is convert the following code:

```
def try_to_make_artwork_from(enumerable)
  enumerable.each do |item|
    result = make_artwork_from item
    return result if result
 end
   nil
end
```

To something like:

```
def try_to_make_artwork_from(enumerable)
  enumerable.try_with { |item| make_artwork_from item }
end
```

What is desirable in the initial code is:

1. It returns `nil` if the block never takes a truthy value;
2. It returns the value of the block the first time it is truthy;
3. It stops after finding the first match;
4. It does not call `make_artwork_from` again (let us say it is not guaranteed to return the same result the next time you call it).

What is not so desirable, is that uses `result` three times, yet it has nothing to do with the story.

EDIT: Sorry, the initial implementation was incorrect, it needed to return `nil` in the case the block value was never true.

```
enumerable.lazy.map(&:block).detect(&:itself)
```

does the job, but is the simplest way? Is it efficient compare to simply using an `each` and caching the value?

Comment: What do you mean by "value of the block", do you mean the argument passed to the block or what the block returns? Maybe I'm missing something but isn't this the purpose of [`Enumerable#find`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-find)

Comment: Perhaps it is just me, but I don't understand your question. Wouldn't `enumerable.detect { |item| make_artwork_from(item) }` return exactly the desired output?

Comment: @spickermann OP wants the method to return the value of `make_artwork_from(item)`. Your code above will return the value of `item`.

Comment: Yes, the lazy enumerable you included in your question is the correct, easiest and fastest way to accomplish this.

Comment: @meagar : Just curious, why did you delete your answer?

Comment: @EricDuminil Because I realized the question had the identical code snippet edited into it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> it does the job, but is the simplest way? Is it efficient compare to
>   simply using a each and caching the value?

## Simplest way?

We can define this method :

```
def first_truthy_block(enumerable, &block)
  enumerable.lazy.map(&block).find(&:itself)
end
```

Here in action :

```
array = [0,1,2,3,4,:x5,'abc']

puts first_truthy_block(array) { |x|
  if x ** 2 > 10 then
    "ARTWORK with #{x}!!!"
  end
} 
#=> ARTWORK with 4!!!
```

Could it be simpler?

- `enumerable` is needed, it's the object you're working on.
- `lazy` is needed, it wouldn't stop as soon as possible, and would throw an exception with `:x5**2`.
- map is needed, you need to apply some method to your element
- find is needed to extract one value at most out of your enumerable

With standard `Enumerable` methods, I don't see how it could be any simpler.

## Is it efficient?

It is slower than your `each` method. It does basically the same thing and should have the same complexity but it does use more method calls and creates more objects :

```
require 'fruity'

def first_truthy_block_lazy(enumerable, &block)
  enumerable.lazy.map(&block).find(&:itself)
end

def first_truthy_block_each(enumerable, &block)
  enumerable.each do |item|
    result = block.call(item)
    return result if result
 end
   nil
end

big_array = Array.new(10_000){rand(4)} + [5] + Array.new(10_000){rand(20)} + [:x, :y, 'z']

compare do
  _lazy_map do
    first_truthy_block_lazy(big_array) { |x|
      if x ** 2 > 10 then
        "ARTWORK with #{x}!!!"
      end
    }
  end

  _each do       
    first_truthy_block_each(big_array) { |x|
      if x ** 2 > 10 then
        "ARTWORK with #{x}!!!"
      end
    }
  end
end
```

fruity returns :

```
Running each test once. Test will take about 1 second.
_each is faster than _lazy_map by 3x ± 0.1
```

Comment: Downvoter : constructive criticism is always welcome!

Answer (score 1):

## Calling the method twice

Looking at your first example of `stuff_in_trash.detect(&:eatable?)`, you could do the following:

```
stuff_in_trash.detect(&:eatable?)&.eatable?
```

Note the use of the [safe navigation operator](http://mitrev.net/ruby/2015/11/13/the-operator-in-ruby/) (`&.`), available as of ruby `v2.3+`, which covers the edge case of `detect` returning `nil`.

Pros:

- You are not looping through the full `stuff_in_trash` list, as the `detect?` method stops at the first truthy item.

Cons:

- You're calling the `eatable?` method twice, on the truthy object. (Possible performance issue, and generally bad practice.)
- The code could get ugly/confusing; especially if the method you apply in the `detect` block is more complicated. For example: `make_artwork_from( items.detect {|item| make_item_from(item)}` - and that's without even covering the possible issue of `detect` returning `nil` yet!

## Using a lazy enumerator

Looking at your second example of `make_artwork_from(item)`, you could do the following:

```
items.lazy.map {|item| make_artwork_from(item)}.detect(&:itself)
```

Pros:

- You are not looping through the full `items` list, as the **lazy** enumerator queries the "minimum" number of items to calculate the final method chain's result.
- You're only calling `make_artwork_from(item)` *once* on the "truthy" object.

Cons:

- It's [a bit more complicated](http://patshaughnessy.net/2013/4/3/ruby-2-0-works-hard-so-you-can-be-lazy) exactly how this approach works under the hood...

## Extending the Enumerable class

Fairly self-explanatory - you could define a method like:

```
module Enumerable
  def detect_result
    self.detect do |i|
      if result = yield(i)
        return result
      end
    end
  end
end

# Usage:
items.detect_result { |item| make_artwork_from(item) }
```

Pros:

- You are not looping through the full `items` list, as the extended class method prematurely `return`s if a truthy value is found.
- You're only calling `make_artwork_from(item)` *once* on the "truthy" object.

Cons:

- Globally extending core classes like this is generally a bad idea! You could consider making it a [refinement](https://ruby-doc.org/core/doc/syntax/refinements_rdoc.html) instead, although these are not widely used.

## Write it as a function, not a method

...By which I mean, pass the `Enumerable` object as a method parameter, rather than calling a method on the object. Similar to above, but instead implemented like:

```
def detect_result(enumerable)
  enumerable.detect do |i|
    if result = yield(i)
      return result
    end
  end
end

# Usage:
detect_result(items) { |item| make_artwork_from(item) }
```

Pros:

Same as above.

Cons:

- This is not very object-oriented; so is arguably not "the ruby way" to handle this. There's nothing stopping you from passing a non-enumerable object to `detect_result`, which could cause runtime errors!
- In other, statically typed, languages (`C++`, `Java`, `Rust`, `Scala`, ...) the above con would be a non-issue.

---

Personally, I think using a lazy enumerator is the most elegant, generic solution. But I wanted to include some alternatives for comparison.

Comment: 1. `items.lazy.select {|item| make_artwork_from(item)}.first` will not work; 2. You can replace `enumerable.each` with `enumerable.detect` to avoid redundant  `return` (I got caught with this too).

Comment: and 3. There is no functions in Ruby :)

Comment: 1. Yes it does??!! Try it! 2. Yeah, true. Good point, I'll edit. 3. *squirm*... Kind of... Sort of.... Ish... :D Maybe I should have written "function" in quotation marks

Comment: 1. No it really doesn't.

Comment: 1. No it really doesn't.

Comment: `[1,2,3].lazy.select {|item| 42 if item == 2 }.first` will return 2, while a desirable result is 42

Comment: Ahhh whoops sorry, my bad. Well, that's trivial to fix, without changing the general approach: `[1,2,3].lazy.map {|item| 42 if item == 2 }.select(&:itself)`

Comment: Aye.... `[1,2,3].lazy.map {|item| 42 if item == 2 }.detect(&:itself)`. It's been a long day. :(

Answer (score 1):

```
array.inject(nil) {|c,v| c or m(v)}
```

Comment: What's confusing about it?  It expands to nil or m(array[0]) or m(array[1]) or ...

Comment: The only difference in terms of behavior is the fact that ``array.inject(nil) {|c,v| c or m(v)}`` will keep iterating on the enumerable even though the block will never be called again. If one is only interested in never calling the block once it is no longer necessary, and not concerned with iterating over a huge enumerable, yours is arguably a much cleaner solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can extend Enumerable with the desired iterator:

```
module Enumerable
  def detect_return
    self.detect do |i|
      r = yield(i) and return r
    end
  end
end

[1, 2, 3].detect_return do |i|
   if i + 1 >= 2
     puts "I will be printed only once"
     "ok, here I am"
   end
end
# I will be printed only once
# => "ok, here I am"
```

As far as we all agree that monkey patching is a bad stuff, let's provide less harming variant:

```
def detect_return(enumerable)
  enumerable.detect do |i|
    r = yield(i) and return r
  end
end

detect_return([1, 2, 3]) do |i|
  if i + 1 >= 2
    puts "I will be printed only once"
    "ok, here I am"
  end
end
# I will be printed only once
# => "ok, here I am"

detect_return([1, 2, 3]) do |i|
  if i + 1 >= 42
    puts "I will be printed only once"
    "ok, here I am"
  end
end
# => nil
```

Comment: You *can* extend Enumerable, but patching core classes is pretty much never the answer.

Comment: @meagar True, monkey patching is generally a bad idea ;)

Comment: The identity this answer's author became evident when I read `yield(i) and return r` (as opposed to `yield(i) && return r`). :-)

Comment: @CarySwoveland ;) there is a reason: they are two independent statements and `and` in this case is an equivalent of `\n` or `;` while `&&` will behave in *this particular situation* the same way, but it will have some side effects and it is not an equivalent of `\n` or `;`. For me `and`/`or` are mostly for decoration reasons, while `&&`/`||` are for logical operations.

Answer (score 0):

(from  https://makandracards.com/makandra/35569-how-to-iterate-over-an-enumerable-returning-the-first-truthy-result-of-a-block-map-find)

You can simply use `break`:

```rb
# "pseudo" code
my_enum.find do |item|
  calculated_result = begin
    # some stuf
  end

  break calculated_result if my_condition_is_true
end


# Or from the given link exemple 
first_image_url = posts.find do |post|
  break post.image.url if post.image.present?
end
```